# How to get name of template that was chosen for request?

Tags: templating

For convenience it would be rather useful if there was a way for me to achieve the following inside my main layout template:

```
<body class="template--{{ getNameOfPageTemplateHere|replace({ '/':'-', '_':'' }) }}">
```

Such that a page rendered using the template "blog/_entry" would have the following body tag:

```
<body class="template--blog-entry">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the solution you was looking for, but here is an alternative solution I'm using.

Put a Twig block in your "master template" (_layout.html?) like this:

```
<body class="{% block bodyClass %}{% endblock bodyClass %}">
```

And from my templates I can **add** classes to the body tag like this:

```
{% block bodyClass %}{{ parent() }} news-index anotherclass{% endblock bodyClass %}
```

Or **replace** the classes by omitting the parent() like this:

```
{% block bodyClass %}news-index anotherclass{% endblock bodyClass %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have something like this, I am using a variable rather than a block which gets set before `@extends` but I was hoping to avoid having to explicitly set the class for each of my templates, would have been nice if this could be automated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{% set templateName = _self.getTemplateName() %}` from `_edit` and pass that up as a variable that your layout template can utilize.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not seem to return the name of the template that is dealing with the request, but rather the name of the current template; '_layout.html' in my case.

Comment: And you put the `getTemplateName()` call inside of the `_edit` template?